# Flambe Could not find 'closure.jar'

Tags: flashdevelop, haxe

I'm trying to use Flambe with Haxe in FlashDevelop, and when building I get an error:

Could not find 'closure.jar'

Anyone any idea why this is?

[image]

My Haxe is properly installed, and I followed the installation thingy for Flambe from the wiki:

```
haxelib install flambe
haxelib run flambe setup
```

It detected my FlashDevelop and I made a new project using the template. I'm trying to build that new project, without modifications.

(You can get the log file here: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/10448192/MTG%20Web/Flambe/build/config_stackoverflow.log )

Edit: I have Python 2.7, can that be a problem?

Thanks a lot!

-P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a full reinstall (FlashDevelop + Haxe + Flambe + Python) and now it works. Something (no idea what) apparently went wrong last time.

Answer (score 1):

What about reporting this issue?
https://github.com/aduros/flambe/issues

Comment: That's a good idea, let's do that :D Thought it was a problem with my setup :s